# How to close pdf file from R

Tags: r, pdf

How do you close a pdf file from R? When I write a pdf-file from R i would like to be able to close it first (if it is open).

I have this code:

```
pdf(file="test.pdf", paper="a4")
...
dev.off()
```

I would like to close the pdf-file test.pdf before I run the code

Comment: Since R doesn't know what program you've opened the pdf in, you might just have to kill the pdf reader process, e.g.: `system('taskkill /f /im AcroRd32.exe')`. But this will kill all instances of Acrobat Reader, I believe.

Comment: Use a proper pdf reader that allows you to overwrite a pdf while it's open.  I use sumatra (http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/download-free-pdf-viewer.html)

Comment: @jbaums please change your comment to an answer. The I will ok it

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve this is to kill the pdf reader process. In Windows, this can be done with `taskkill`, which can be called from R as follows:

```
system('taskkill /f /im AcroRd32.exe')
```

**The above will kill all instances of Acrobat Reader.**

Answer (score 0):

For Foxit Reader in my case:

```
system('TASKKILL /f /fi "Imagename eq Foxit Reader.exe"')
```

OR

```
system('taskkill /f /t /im FoxitReader.exe')
```