# opening a pdf file while R is open

Tags: r, pdf

I write into a pdf file using `pdf("tree.pdf")`
I close the pdf using `dev.off()`

Apparently, when I try to open `tree.pdf` while I'm in R, I get the error message:

> There was an error opening this document.
>   This file is already open or in use by another application.

Therefore, I have to close R in order to watch the file that I created. What can I do in order to watch the file without closing R?

Comment: It's difficult say without a minimal working example. Try loading up a clean R session, writing a simple plot (e.g `plot(1:10)`) to a pdf and then calling `dev.off()`. If you can open that pdf, I suspect you had the device open more than once. You can also try `graphics.off()` which closes all devices.

Comment: Try using `dev.off()`twice.

Comment: Your PDF is possibly blocked by your PDF reader.  Use a PDF reader that supports writing while the file is open.  I use Sumatra PDF.  http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23381435/602276

Answer (score 1):

At Windows 8 it works as follows:

```
system("taskkill /f /im AcroRd32.exe")
```